# How to set up indexes for dynamic filtering queries in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-performance, performance-tuning

Given I have SOURCE_EVENT table in Oracle:

```
create table SOURCE_EVENT
(
    ID                   NUMBER(19)                             not null
        constraint PK_SOURCE_EVENT
            primary key,
    SOURCE_SYSTEM        VARCHAR2(50 char)                      not null,
    EVENT_TYPE           VARCHAR2(60 char),
    EVENT_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP(6),
    CONTRACT_NUMBER      VARCHAR2(255 char),
    PERSON_CUID          NUMBER(19),
)
/
```

I want to effectively filter by all columns in this table and filtering should be dynamic, i.e. user can select in UI any combination of input fields.

I also use paging to display pages of 10 source events and total number of source events.

Current situation is I have 30 million rows stored in this table.

Examples of queries:

```
select *
from (select s.id              as id,
             s.source_system   as source_system,
             s.event_type      as event_type,
             s.event_timestamp as event_timestamp,
             s.contract_number as contract_number,
             s.person_cuid     as person_cuid
      from SOURCE_EVENT s
      where s.source_system = 'source' AND s.event_type = 'event'
      order by s.id desc)
where rownum <= 10;

select
    count(s.id) as count
from
    SOURCE_EVENT s
where
    s.event_timestamp between TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-22 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9') and TO_TIMESTAMP(
            '2020-10-23 23:59:59.999999999', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9')
```

What is recommended way how to set up indexes?

Taking into consideration all combinations of predicates can be used

Answer (score 0):

> Taking into consideration all combinations of predicates can be used

One option would be a `bitmap index` on the non `ID`, non TIMESTAMP column.

One index per column.

Beware of its it's downsides.

- serialization
- possible slower DML

Luckily, the newer versions of Oracle allow you to experiment with indexing strategies.

Comment: What about ID and TIMESTAMP columns?